# Access response body in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi im currently trying to implement a way to pay with paypal according to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/checkout/configure-payments/multiseller-payments/ and im using their node code. How can i access the response body?

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');

express()
    .post('/my-server/create-order', function(req, res) {
        request.post('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/json",
                'Authorization': "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
                'PayPal-Partner-Attribution-Id': "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
            },
            body: {
                "intent": "CAPTURE",
                "purchase_units": [{
                    "amount": {
                        "currency_code": "USD",
                        "value": "100.00"
                    },
                    "payee": {
                        "email_address": "seller@example.com"
                    },
                    "payment_instruction": {
                        "disbursement_mode": "INSTANT",
                        "platform_fees": [{
                            "amount": {
                                "currency_code": "USD",
                                "value": "25.00"
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }],
            },
            json: true
        }, function(err, response, body) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return res.sendStatus(500);
            }
            else{
                console.log(response)
            }
            res.json({
                id: body.id
            });
            
        });
    });
```

Comment: Instead of `express().post // [...]`, people generally do `const app = express()` and later `app.post // [...]`.

Comment: What does response log? Do you not have your desired data there ?